# How to find postgresql uri for SQLALCHEMY config

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect my flask app to my prostgreSQL db, and i find this configuration example (below code). I just do not know how to find my postgreSQL URI

```
app = Flask(__name__)
#how do i know my postgresql URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://localhost/pre-registration'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the documentation of SQLAlchemy (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#database-urls):

> The typical form of a database URL is:
>
> dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database

This means that, if you have a Postgres DB called my_db running on localhost on port 5432, accessed by username *user* and password *pass*, your URL will look like:

> postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/my_db